# How do I disable/remove Klipper in KDE Plamsa 5?

Tags: kubuntu, clipboard, plasma-5, kde5, copy-and-paste

Klipper is frequently causing the system to hang on copy/paste actions. This is indicated by my taskbar being non-interactive on copy/paste. This will usually last for 10-30 seconds, or I will restart plasma through the terminal.

How do I disable/remove Klipper?

System Info:

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5 
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0 
Qt Version: 5.15.2 
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-22-generic (64-bit) 
Graphics Platform: X11 
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz 
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM 
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Unless you want to be left unable to use copy/paste, this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).  Can you provide more context and details about the problem?  What applications are being used when the system hangs? Where are you copy/pasting to and from, and how are you doing that. Context menus? Keyboard shortcuts? How did you determine that klipper is responsible and not some other process?  Have you used a resource monitor while the problem is happening?

Comment: @Nmath
I am replacing Klipper with copyq. I remember doing something with Klipper on my last device to disable/remove it. It behaves like intermittently, but it is pretty indiscriminate on the application/environment I am copy/pasting to/from. Another thing it does frequently is fail to copy content on Ctrl+C. Also, even if this is an XY problem, I want to use copyq, so having Klipper would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's part of Plasma-workspace. So not removable without recompiling Plasma. If you need to restart Plasma, use `pkill plasma; plasma plasmashell &`.

https://forum.manjaro.org/t/re-install-klipper-clipboard-manager/48497/4

Answer (score 2):

You just need to open the system tray: right click -> Configure System Tray. Then go to "Entries" and disable the "Clipboard" entry. Add CopyQ to Autostartand reboot

Comment: This doesn't disable Klipper it just hides it from the tray.